# Using Python, how can I stream, over a socket, file blocks interjected with other data?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a binary file and a list of raw data. I want to interject the list's elements between blocks of the file and then transmit it over a socket. I want to use the socket as a pipe between a server and a client.

I would like to send file blocks and raw data chunks, rather than construct a new file and send it as whole, since original file can already be big.

If file's blocks are f1, f2, f3, f4  and list's data is r1, r2, r3, r4 then I would like to transmit the following sequence : r1, f1, r2, f2, r3, f3, r4, f4.

Here's what I've came up so far (suppose every block is 1024 bytes)

Server:

```
import socket

list = [r1,r2,r3,r4]

host= ''
port = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

conn = s.accept()


with open(filepath,'rb') as file:
   for i in range (0,len(list)):
      file.seek(i*1024)
      data = file.read(1024) + list[i]
      conn.sendall(data)  

conn.close()
```

Client :

```
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 8080

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((host,port))


with open(filepath,'ab') as file:
   data = socket.recv(1056)
   if data:
       file.write(data)
   else:
       break

socket.close()
```

Is there any simpler way to implement a "pipe" between client and server?

In any case should the client open a new connection for every (fileblock, hash) pair?

Comment: if you close the connection, yes, a new one have to be made. As for data, you may use 2 socket, one for file,one for list.Or buid your own parser(put a block of chars, like MYDATA) and check on client side, or, if data are splited in 1024 b, read 1024 as data and next as list member.But send list as string of fixed length so that you know where data begin again

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying do is serialize the data over a connection. Luckily this is a problem lots of people have Google for example uses[Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) , Python has Pickle built in and there is a new entrant in [Capt Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/). Check out the protobuf [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial)